# Pictures not showing in gulp build

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a gulp build, everything works fine, but after the build, some images are not loaded and are not displayed because the paths are different, for this I installed gulp-replace. The paths have been successfully replaced, this can be seen in the final code. But the image is not showing on the page.

And every time when I start the assembly, the picture that was missing may appear in the new assembly, but another one will be missing

What's wrong with my build?

[**Link to my gulp code**](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-engelbart-ybvku?file=/package.json)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `const cleanCSS = require("gulp-clean-css");`

As I did not try to rearrange the line with renaming, nothing happened. In the minified file, the paths remain from the src parp. Temporarily removed minification

```js
//Таск для обработки стилей
gulp.task("styles", () => {
 
  return (
    gulp
      .src(styleFiles)
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    
      .pipe(less())

      .pipe(concat("style.css"))
      .pipe(replace('url("../img/', 'url("./../img/'))
     
      .pipe(
        autoprefixer({
          overrideBrowserslist: ["last 2 versions"],
          cascade: false,
        })
      )

      .pipe(sourcemaps.write("./"))
      .pipe(gulp.dest("./build/css"))
      .pipe(browserSync.stream())
  );
});
```